# Python: Workflow about hiding authentication data of a mysql database in python

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a question concerning Python and MySQL. I come from a PHP background and I am wondering how the workflow will be in Python. I can't find any good answers on that on the web and hope anybody can help me understanding this thing. So let me quickly explain what i'm stucked with:

In PHP i did a lot of little things in combination with MySQL, meaning loading data from a database and writing to it. As long as the server on which the php files were stored was correctly set up, it was save to do that. The connection to the database including the username, servername, password and database name was saved in the php file. As php files get stored on the server and the source code won't get shown to the user itself, the user couldn't see the authentication data to connect to the database.

Now, I am wondering how that whole concept can be transfered to Python in a secure way so that the user can't see the authentication data in the source text.
I plan to program a Python program in which the user has to authenticate. Let's assume I created a MySQL database on a webserver and in the Python program the user can login. As soon the user clicks on the login-button a connection to the web-database is done. That would mean that in my source code i need to write down the neccessary data like username, password, db-name and server name for that specific database. Here is my Question: That would mean that everybody could see that authentication data which would be very unsecure, wouldn't it? Even if the user has just a .pyc file he could then recompile it and see the standard .py file in which he could see all that very sensitive data.

So I was wondering how to securely hide that authentication data from the user who will later use my Python program.

Comment: I don't think I got you right, but there is no difference in how PHP and Python work with database. Both are interpreted languages with code being stored in simple text files that can be viewed by anyone who has access to them. You should not have anything like passwords or usernames hardcoded in them, obviously.

Comment: You need to implement a server/client communication. In PHP as you already wrote, you have a special case, where the client can be the server at the same time. In almost all other cases you implement a server which hides the db-connection and deals with user interactions.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer. Maybe I understood something wrong, but in the Python file I need to connect to a mysql database in order to get some data out of it. In php all was fine because the user can never see the actuall php file itself, he just sees a html file which was formed by the php file. So the user can never see the sensitive authentication data. In Python he can because it's in the python source code. Or does the python source code need to send the username and passowrd to the webserver and some other php files will check the entered values?

Comment: And this is the same for python, as long as we are talking about web applications. The HTML will be formed and will contain exactly what you will put there. A user sees only front-end (html page), not the python code, that will handle requests from the user/connecting DB etc

Comment: Understood. But i try to manage something different. Pracitally said: I develop some python scripts for nuke, a compositing software.The user downloads the script and installs it. In nuke he can run the script. For example i he clicks on a button, a window will pop up which displays data from a mysql database which is on my server. All in all: The python script is on the computer of the artist; In that python script a connection to a mysql database which is on a webserver is accomplished; + for safety reasons the user may not see the authentication data to access the web database himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a pythoneer who long time ago was working in php, I think I know what you are after.

First of all, the HTML code will not contain any database credentials unless you put them into the HTML view. An easy way of structuring what goes into the HTML views is to use a framework like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It handles the MVC of web applications and does connections to databases.

If you want your database credentials to be very safe, you can have your web application ask for them at startup, thus never having them written down in a file. Keep them secure using keypass or similar password storage systems.
This way they are also not checked in to any version control system, where the most common place for database password leakage occurs.

If you are a newbie to webapp programming in python, I would suggest to follow a [Django tutorial](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials) it should help you get on the track.

Comment: Thank you very much, firelynx. I'll have a look into Django :-)

Comment: I also suggest you to get familiar with [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org) book, and it's Exercise 50: Your First Website in particular